# installing sliding shower door when width is larger than tub

Tags: bathroom, doors, shower

I'm looking into sliding shower doors and all the doors I see assume that you are installing to space which is the width of the tub. In my case, the end of my tub has a little shelf extending beyond the tub, around 4 inches length and 1 inch higher than the tub. Has anyone seen examples of installs with this?

[image]

Comment: If you install a 60" door into a space that is 56" then your doors will overlap 4" more than they typically do. A picture of the shelf would help.

Comment: Yiu will need to add a short wing wall made of some water proof material on the left side, leaving an opening proper size for pre made doors. Or add a lip of water proof material to tub curb top making a plane even with shelf top, then order custom width doors.

Answer (score 1):

Make a 2” return on each end or 4” one end to support the sliding units which takes up the extra space.

Now you have added the picture I would go for the 4” - designed to match the shelf or just completely box-in that end... but that shelf area could be useful....

Some shower screens don’t go the full length of the bath anyway - I fitted one that is 2/3 of the bath length which works fine for the shower.

Comment: I think he means the door is wider than the tub opening.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose I think the OP means tub length plus shelf ie X + 4” ...

Comment: How does the OP do that ?  I also think the question is that the opening is wider then the tub. I.E. wider then 60 inches.

Comment: @AlaskaMan because of the words “extending beyond the tub”...

Comment: @SolarMike  Beyond would suggest beyond, not into. Beyond 60 inches. I imagine a small cove type built in shelf not a self that intrudes into the tub space. It is ambiguous without further info from the OP. Then again the title states **"installing sliding shower door when width is larger than tub"** width of opening or width of door?  *I think width of opening*.

Comment: @AlaskaMan which is exactly what my answer is dealing with... thise “returns” are small wall extensions...

Comment: I added picture to clarify. Thanks for help. I see I forgot to mention the height difference as well.. added that in

Comment: Thanks for the update Solar Mike. I'm not familiar with what a return is, and google wasn't so helpful. What is a return in this context?

Comment: @Michael as I put in the comment above "these “returns” are small wall extensions", so, a small wall to take up the 4" space and provide a secure solid mounting for the sliding panel...